# how can I get only modified reports by restful api?

Tags: business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I use this to get reports:

```
http://1x.yy.zz.qq:ww05/biprws/raylight/v1/documents?limit=50
```

It returns all reports which id between 1 and 50.

But I want it to get only modified reports?

thanks in advance

Comment: What is a "modified report"?

Comment: its sql changed

Comment: There's no flag in documents to indicate that a SQL change was done.  You'd have to create a process to extract the SQL from all data providers in all documents, save the SQL, then run it again in the future for reports with a newer modified date, and compare the SQL against the original extract.

Comment: Ok, can i put where condition to find report in specific folder